# Generating a string of jQuery for Ajax uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery

My page generates a jQuery string (the jqueryBlock below) that gets ajaxed up to a php file that writes it into a new html file, where it will execute.  The code "A" below is what I have now to generate the final jQuery, "B" below in the new html file.

"A"

```
    var targetName = "redbox";
    target = $('div[filename=' + targetName + ']').hide()[0];
    var jqueryBlock= '<script>$(function() {\n'; 
    jqueryBlock += "$('#" + this.id + "').click(function() {\n";
    jqueryBlock += "$('#" +  target.id + "').show();\n";
    jqueryBlock += "}).css('cursor', 'pointer');\n";
    jqueryBlock += "$('#" +  target.id + "').dblclick(function(){\n$(this).hide();\n});\n";
    jqueryBlock += "})<\/script>";
```

"B"

```
    <script>$(function() {
    $('#T_1376594221987').click(function() {
                             $('#T_1376594237267').show();
                           })
                         .css('cursor', 'pointer');

    $('#T_1376594237267').dblclick(function(){
                            $(this).hide();
                          });
    })</script>
```

This all works, but it's a nightmare to write block A, trying to keep track of the multiple levels of quotes and all the parens and braces and not being able to break lines to make them more readable. I'm thinking that there must be a way to do this where I can write something that looks more like the finished jQuery for "A".  Can anyone suggest a better method?
Thanks.

Comment: `\t` will create a tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, well... I came up with some ideas... you may like some, all, or none of it. But I figured I'd paste it here. Just a couple of techniques. You can view the <kbd>[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p337/vWMAf/)</kbd> as well.

The first, make a function for creating the jQuery selector. This way you can just pass the id, and get your selector, no quotes to worry about.

```
function makeJqIdSelector(id) {
    return "$('#" + id + "')";
}
```

The same way of thinking, you could write functions to wrap something in `<script>` tags (or even a `function`.

```
function wrapScriptTags(scr) {
    return "<script>\n" + scr + "\n<\/script>";
}
```

Finally, you can use an array to join the elements so you don't have to keep typing out `\n`s. ie:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push("a",
         "b",
         "c"
          );
var str = arr.join("\n");
//output:
//a 
//b
//c
```

This has the added effect of being more efficient as well. (probably not an issue for modern browsers, and especially not for this few strings)

---

Here it is all together:

```
var thisSelect = makeJqIdSelector(this.id);
var targetSelect = makeJqIdSelector(target.attr('id'));

var jblock = [];
jblock.push(
    "$(function() {", 
    thisSelect + ".click(function() {", 
    targetSelect + ".show();",
    "}).css('cursor', 'pointer');", 
    targetSelect + ".dblclick(function(){\n$(this).hide();",
    "});",
    "});"
);
var jqueryBlock = wrapScriptTags(jblock.join("\n"));
```

#### output

```
<script>
$(function() {
$('#T_1376594221987').click(function() {
$('#T_1376594237267').show();
}).css('cursor', 'pointer');
$('#T_1376594237267').dblclick(function(){
$(this).hide();
});
});
</script>
```

Note: Obviously, I did not spend a lot of time making sure the output was perfect. It was just for the technique - I have no real way of testing it.

Comment: This all looks great! And thanks for putting the jsfiddle together.I'll charge off in this direction.  I expect it will make the task much simpler.

Comment: Yes, after working with this a few hours, it's definitely the way to go.  One advantage I didn't see at first is that the array of strings lets you type in as many spaces as you want in each line, so you can you indent the lines to look very close to what you want to produce in the end file.

Comment: Glad it's working out. It sounds like a very interesting project.

Answer (score 1):

If I understanded everything, you could ajax up only the dynamic variables to the PHP file, and change it to something like this:

```
<script>$(function() {
$('#<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>').click(function() {
                         $('#<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>').show();
                       })
                     .css('cursor', 'pointer');

$('#<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>').dblclick(function(){
                        $(this).hide();
                      });
})</script>
```

Comment: Nice thought, but I have a lot of different jquery code blocks to pass up and I'd have to have a companion php function to expand each one. I think I'd like to stick with creating the jQuery  on the client, if I can.

Comment: It is a very good practice to only transfer data from client to server, never functionality. If you transfer behavior it's a lot easier to find a security breach on your site. Nevertheless, I understand your concern with legacy code, at this point it *may* be worse just to think about changing a lot of different points of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

In coffeescript you can use a text block that keeps track of the indention level for you. Maybe you can change to coffeescript just for this script.

http://coffeescript.org/#strings